# FORM (uses Javascript) not working in a PHP page!

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit

I have a simple subscribe form at : http://thepanamainsider.com/sanblas/index9.php
The form doesn't work, it is using JS.
The same HTML code with the JS code when written in a separate HTML page ( http://thepanamainsider.com/form1.html ) works without any issue.

The PHP page can be downloaded from:

http://manishkungwani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/indexORG.zip

Please help me as to how can I make the form run?

**Clarification:**
It doesn't work means that it is supposed to redirect to a PDF and send a mail to the user.
The form.php recieving the POST request works fine, if the POST is sent from the HTML page, thus I anticipate that there is an issue with the request being sent or an issue with the validation.
The button redirects to the same page!

**Further Clarification:**
*The question was bound to remain unsolved because the code that was written was too bad, another developer had used a sample page to create the current page! (bad practice)*
I resolved the issue by rewriting the page in only HTML and now everything works fine.
Yet the closest reply has been marked the answer as the anticipated issue was VALIDATION.
sorry for the waste of time. (if any :) )

Comment: Define "doesn't work" please. What do you do? What do you expect to happen in response to that? What actually happens?

Comment: +1 for your clarification, manish. That's much, _much_ better and I sorely wish that we saw more of it on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have in your php code

```
  document.pay1.submit();
```

There is no such element in your code as pay1 which is causing javascript error

Comment: so you removed this code, but left it on webpage.. if you want any help, we need to work on last version.

Comment: The updated file has been uploaded on the server, please go through the server and see if you can find the solution!